# How to output the vector of string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

```
else if (answer == 's') // case 2. Sort
{
    vector<string> theArray[countToken];

    for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
    {
        theArray[i].push_back(token[i]);
    }

    quickSort(*theArray, 0, countToken - 1);

    cout << "=====SORTED=====\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
    {
        cout << theArray[i] << "  ";
    }
}
```

I am so confuse on how to output the `theArray[i]`.
I define the `theArray` of `vector<string>` `theArray[countToken]`.

The Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

static const int MIN_SIZE = 2;
char dc = ',';
bool TRACE = false;

void show(vector<string>& theArray, int first, int last)
{
    cout << "(";
    for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
        cout << theArray[i] << " ";
    cout << ")\n";
}
void menu()
{
    cout << "=====Menu=====\n" << "Default delimiter is " << dc << " \n";
    if (TRACE)
        cout << "Trace is ON\n";
    else
        cout << "Trace is OFF\n";
    cout << "n. New List\n" << "s. Quick Sort\n" << "t. Trace mode\n" << "d. Delimiter char\n" << "q. Quit\n" << "Enter your choice: \n";
}

void insertionSort(vector<string>& theArray, int first, int n)
{
    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; unsorted++)
    {
        string nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;

        for (loc, nextItem; (loc > 0) && (theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem); loc--)
        {
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            //loc--;
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem; // Insert nextItem into sorted region
    } // end for
} // end insertionSort

void order(vector < string > & theArray, int i, int j)
{
    if (theArray[i] > theArray[j])
        std::swap(theArray[i], theArray[j]); // Exchange entries
} // end order

int sortFirstMiddleLast(vector < string > & theArray, int first, int last)
{
    if (TRACE) show(theArray, first, last);
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]
    order(theArray, mid, last); // Make theArray[mid] <= theArray[last]
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]
    if (TRACE) show(theArray, first, last);
    return mid;
} // end sortFirstMiddleLast


int partition(vector<string>& theArray, int first, int last)
{
    // Choose pivot using median-of-three selection
    int pivotIndex = sortFirstMiddleLast(theArray, first, last);

    // Reposition pivot so it is last in the array
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[last - 1]);
    pivotIndex = last - 1;
    string pivot = theArray[pivotIndex];

    // Determine the regions S1 and S2
    int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
    int indexFromRight = last - 2;

    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        // Locate first entry on left that is >= pivot
        while (theArray[indexFromLeft] < pivot)
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;

        // Locate first entry on right that is <= pivot
        while (theArray[indexFromRight] > pivot)
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;

        if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight)
        {
            std::swap(theArray[indexFromLeft], theArray[indexFromRight]);
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
        }
        else
            done = true;
    } // end while

    // Place pivot in proper position between S1 and S2, and mark its new location
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[indexFromLeft]);
    pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

    return pivotIndex;
} // end partition

void quickSort(vector<string>& theArray, int first, int last)
{
    if (last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE)
    {
        insertionSort(theArray, first, last);
    }
    else if (TRACE)
    {
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);

        quickSort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
        if (TRACE) show(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
        quickSort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        if (TRACE) show(theArray, pivotIndex - 1, last);
    } // end if
    else
    {
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last);

        quickSort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
        cout << "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
            cout << theArray[i] << " ";
        cout << ")\n";
        quickSort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        cout << "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
            cout << theArray[i] << " ";
        cout << ")\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> token;
    int countToken;
    while (1)
    {
        char answer;
        menu();
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore(1000, 10);

        if (answer == 'n') // case 1. Input String
        {
            string input;
            cout << "Enter new list: ";
            getline(cin, input);

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == dc)
                    count++;
            }
            token.clear();
            countToken = count + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
            {
                int x = input.find(dc);
                token.push_back(input.substr(0, x));
                input = input.substr(x + 1);
            }

            cout << endl << "=====Current String=====\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
            {
                cout << token[i] << " ";
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (answer == 's') // case 2. Sort
        {
            vector<string> theArray[countToken];

            for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
            {
                theArray[i].push_back(token[i]);
            }

            quickSort(*theArray, 0, countToken - 1);

            cout << "=====SORTED=====\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
            {
                cout << theArray[i] << "  ";
            }
        }
        else if (answer == 't')
        {
            TRACE = true;
            cout << "Toggle Trace mode is ON\n";
        }
        else if (answer == 'd')
        {
            cout << "Enter a new delimiter char: ";
            cin >> dc;
        }
        else if (answer == 'q')
        {
            cout << "\nProgram END." << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Invalid input !" << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    } // while
    return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: Wait...so you know how to do an insertion sort, but are having trouble looping over the contents of a vector...?

Comment: I do not think this means what you think it means: `vector<string> theArray[countToken];` What was your intent there? A native C++ array? A single vector? Or an *array of vectors*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you wrote for outputting the vector.  The problem is the vector declaration itself.  You've mixed up C-style array declarators with C++ constructor syntax.

The result is you declared an array of `countToken` string vectors.  When you walk through adding data, you are pushing just one string into each one of those vectors.  When you call `quickSort`, you're only passing the first of those vectors.

Since you already know how many items you want to put in the vector, you can create an empty vector, reserve the storage to avoid unnecessary vector resizing, and then use `push_back`.

```
vector<string> theArray;
theArray.reserve(countToken);

for (int i = 0; i < countToken; i++)
{
    theArray.push_back(token[i]);
}

quickSort(theArray, 0, countToken - 1);
```

But I notice that you are just pushing items straight out of the `token` vector, and that vector has `countToken` items in it.  So why not just copy it like this:

```
vector<string> theArray(token);
quickSort(theArray, 0, countToken - 1);
```

For more information on the available `vector` constructors, see here: [std::vector::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Thanks, I can output now, but I still have other problem in my code,,

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
vector<string> theArray[countToken];
```

you create an array of vector objects.
I think you intended to just create a vector object.
Do:

```
vector<string> theArray;
```

and use:

```
theArray.push_back(val);
```

To print out, put

```
#include <algorithm>
```

at the top of your file and do:

```
for_each(theArray.begin(), theArray.end(), [] (string& s){ cout << s << " "; });
```

or you can do:

```
vector<string>::iterator it;
for(it = theArray.begin(); it != theArray.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Comment: Not  `cout << *it << endl;`?